# separar palabras de otros caracteres

Tags: javascript

en JavaScript, necesito poder separar palabras de otros caracteres, pero manteniendo toda la cadena, solo agregando espacios al comienzo, y al final de cada palabra.

Supongamos que utilizara solo split con una cadena, me quedaria algo asi...

```
['const', '[value,', 'setValue]', '=', 'useState(datos)']
```

Mi idea es que las palabras sean elementos independientes dentro de un array, para poder agregarles etiquetas y atributos...deberia quedar asi,

```js
[,'const','[','value',',','setValue',']',',','='',' ,'useState','(','datos',')',']'

let c = "const [value, setValue] = useState(datos)"
```

Mi código es ese, pero debe ser una solución un tanto rudimentaria, si alguien me ayuda, muchas gracias!

```js
let n = c.split("")
//console.log(n)

let expReg = /\W/
let mr = n.map(el => {
    if(expReg.test(el)){    
        return el
    }else{
        return [...el]
    }
})
console.log(mr)

let z = n.join(" ")
//console.log(z)


let jk = []

for(let el of mr){
    if(Array.isArray(el)){
        jk.push(el)
    }else{
        jk.push(" " + el + " ")
    }
}
console.log(jk)
// let ij = [...jk]
let ms = jk.join("")
console.log(ms)

codigo.innerHTML = ms
let lo = ms.split(" ")

console.log(lo)
```

Comment: estas tratando de procesar caracteres que significan algo, quieres crear algún parser o tu propio lenguaje??

Comment: Es para hacer un marcado propio de sintaxis o resaltado con clases, y a su vez un ejercicio.

Comment: dame un momento, voy a publicar una respuesta

Comment: La verdad es que no entiendo que quieres hacer, al principio dices "manteniendo toda la cadena" y mas adelante "elementos independientes dentro de un array", quiza deberías incluír un ejemplo calro de la entrada y salida que deseas .

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar muchas gracias @CandidMoe que me ha ayudado a trabajar en mi tokenizer y es de este del cual ha surgido este código. Lo he pasado de python a JavaScript. Lo que hace este es separar un string según los caracteres que encuentre.
Creo que sigue siendo algo rudimentario ya que está hecho desde cero, sin usar expresiones regulares ni ninguna "trampa".

```js
let stream = "const [value, setValue] = useState(datos)"

function separador(stream){
    operadores = "=[](),+-" //definimos algunos operadores
    let linea = stream.trim(); //limpiamos la cadena
    let largo = stream.length;
    let i = 0;
    let car,inicio;
    let result = [] //aqui guardamos el resultado
    
    while (i<largo){
        inicio = i; 
        //omitimos los espacios en blanci
        while(linea[i]===" " && i<largo){
            i++;
        }
        if(i==largo){
            brreak
        }
        car = linea[i]
        //si el caracter se encuentra en los operadores
        if(operadores.includes(linea[i])){
            result.push(car) //añadimos al array y seguimos
            i++
        }
        else if("'\"".includes(car)){ //en caso el caracter sea una comilla simple o doble
            inicio = i
            i++
            while(i<largo && linea[i]!==car){ //iteramos hasta donde se cierre la comilla
                i++ 
            }
            n = linea.slice(inicio,i+1)
            result.push(n)
            i++
        }
        else{
            inicio = i
            i++
            while(i<largo && !(operadores.includes(linea[i])) &&linea[i]!==" "){
                i++
            }
            result.push(linea.slice(inicio,i))
        }
    }
    return result;
}

string_separado = separador(stream);
console.log(string_separado)
```

Esto lo que hace es identificar algunos caracteres e ir separando el string de acuerdo a esos caracteres que hallamos definido, en este caso pueden ser corchetes (`[]`), paréntesis (`()`), algún operador aritmético (`+-/`) o una comilla simple o doble. Cualquier duda que tengas me la puedes hacer en los comentarios :D

Comment: Lo mismo se puede lograr con algo como `stream.split(/(\=|\[|\]|\(|\)|,|\+|-)/g);`

Comment: @Emeeus no sé mucho de js y desconocía que split podría funcionar así. Como dije, lo mío es algo más rudimentario y más que todo sirve para conocer el funcionamiento de lo que se pide.

Comment: Además le servirá para después crear algún tokenizer o separar cada elemento como un token que tenga una identificación

Comment: Ahora que me doy cuenta, tu split no separa los strings :)

Comment: No sé si sirve, en verdad no entiendo la pregunta de OP..

Comment: Bueno muchas gracias a ambos por su gran ayuda.